# How can I manage web hosting locally?

Tags: http, nginx, dns, web-hosting, dedicated

I currently own a dedicated server running Windows Server 2022 that I pay monthly for. I'm just hosting some older games for some friends. The server's got 64gb ram, 2tb hdd, some good specs. I only use about 20% memory and cpu at peak times.

I have an admin tool plugin that opens a web server on: http://myserversip:1624 which gives a webfront to kick players, manage servers, etc. I want to convert this to a domain like servers.mywebsite.com instead of that ugly IP.

I need some advice, should I buy the domain and ssl then that's it? Do I need to host a web server locally? I don't want to pay separately for web hosting as I only have a tiny community and I don't need a complete website.

P.S the current website hosted on my server is publicly accessible, I just want it to be converted to a domain name instead of the IP with the port.

Thank you guys.

I haven't tried much myself as I'm looking for advice first. The existing product is working, I just need help advancing it.